# Show my own errors while any system error occurs in YII

Tags: php, yii

I need to show my own error messages while any system error will come.

i am using `YII Framework`   with modular directory.

i don't want to show error like below image to end users. instead of below error is want to show my own errors text. is it possible?

[image]

below code is my index.php

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',false); # true in while dibuging @$shok

// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);

Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run(); ?>
```

Comment: in places where code throw exceptions provide redirect to your own error page and put exception into log file may be with notifying admin by email.

Comment: I think you can use  'yiiDebug' => false, in production mode and locally use 'yiiDebug' => true in main.php file

Comment: share your index.php

Comment: @Rishabh i made  'yiiDebug' => false but it just redirecting the page to default page. instead redirect i need to show my own error page with my own text.

Comment: Then you can use own custom error page  (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/47/how-to-use-default-layout-for-error-pages-instead-of-errorxxx-views/)